# Inverse square law, but with multiple sources

Tags: visible-light

I'm making a raytracing renderer, and I'm implementing lights. I read about the inverse square law, which I'm sure you know as:

$$intensity = \frac{k}{distance^2}$$

So for each point on an object I calculate the intensity like this, where $k$ is the *energy* of a light. However, what if there are multiple lights? How would I calculate the final intensity of a point?

Before anyone asks, I *have* searched for this on the web, but haven't found any relevant solutions.

A few solutions I've thought about, are:

$$intensity = \sum_n\frac{k_n}{distance_n^2}$$

So basically summing all of the intensities.

Another option would be

$$intensity = \prod_n\frac{k_n}{distance_n^2}$$

*i.e.* multiplying the intensities, but I don't think that would work if you consider any of the intensities being 0.

So is there some way of doing this, which I haven't found by googling my title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In optics, the intensity of unpolarized incoherent light (i.e. white light that you would want to use in a raytracer) is additive, so adding together the intensities should work fine for a renderer, as long as you're not worried about things like diffraction or polarization.

Comment: Great, that makes it easy.

Comment: (I can't accept the answer for another 10 minutes - thanks for the fast response)

Answer (score 0):

Your equation 
$$intensity = \sum_n\frac{k_n}{distance_n^2}$$
is correct.

"..lumens (and lux and candela etc etc) are linearly additive but perceived brightness is logarithmic."

from:

http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?189362-Do-lumens-add-up